# How do I make kapt gradle task showing errors in Kotlin code instead of generated Java code?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt, kapt

I'm using kapt for hilt and room. Whenever there is an error related to those libraries, kapt show me all errors in the generated Java code. How do I make it to show errors in Kotlin code instead?
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbGV8.png) is what it looks like in Android studio.

Just to clarify. It works fine for a valid code. But when there is a mistake (like a missing `@Entity` annotation on an actual entity class) I want it to point the error in Kotlin code, not in generated Java code.

Here is my project's build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version "1.6.10" apply false
}
```

And the app's build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'org.acanthite.upc'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.acanthite.upc"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
ext {
    compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
    room_version = '2.5.0'
    hilt_version = '2.45'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.2'
}
```

I've tried clearing Android Studio caches, rebuild and sync it a ton of times, lovered rooms version, but still no luck. It's basicaly just a project generated from Compose template. Plus I added room and hilt dependencies that I've added on top of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's just the way KAPT works. Migrating to KSP helped, but I digged tons of google pages to find how to do it properly. The official doc (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html) only explains how to use it if you're a library developer. There is nothing there for mere mortals who just want to use KSP plugin for gradle. At least I could not find it there.

Anyway, here is project's build.gradle after migration to KSP (and to Kotlin 1.8.10):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.10-1.0.9' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

App's build.gradle after migration:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'org.acanthite.upc'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.acanthite.upc"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
ext {
    compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
    room_version = '2.5.0'
    hilt_version = '2.45'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.2'
}
```

### Pay attention to these line in project's build.gradle:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.10-1.0.9' apply false
```

You must find matching ksp version here: https://github.com/google/ksp/releases

For example, if your kotlin-android plugin is `1.8.10`, then you need to find ksp release that has first part matching `1.8.10` and the second part as high, as possible. In my case it's `1.8.10-1.0.9`.

#### If you're using compose

You also need to pay attention to this one (app's build.gradle):

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
}
```

Go to here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility
and find the version that matches your kotlin version. In my case `1.4.2` is for kotlin `1.8.10`.

### That's how you do it, except...

This does not work for Dagger/Hilt becase they don't have support for KSP yet. Here is the issue: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2349

So you're basically stuck with Dagger/Hilt untill they add support for KSP.

Have fun.